# I lost all my code when terminated eclipse from ubuntu terminal

Tags: eclipse, terminal

I started Eclipse via the Ubuntu Terminal. After working on my new project for an hour and saving it many times with Ctrl + s, i terminated Eclipse from terminal again. I went back to Eclipse and i saw that there is only the project folder but none of the classes are in it. 
I found the files in the working directory but still can't see in Eclipse. 
I tried refreshing the project but didn't work. I have no idea why it happened.
Any ideas would be appreciated. I can provide more information if you ask.

Comment: Did you add other directories to the project's build path?  What do you mean by "in the working directory" ?  The right place for source files that are part of an eclipse project is under the project directory, so you could just move/copy the files there and then refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure that (1) you're using the same workspace, (2) the project is created correctly with source and build target folders stored separately.

It would help if you could specify what programming language you're working with, which version of Eclipse, and perhaps what your filesystem structure looks like.  The .project and .settings file contents wouldn't hurt, either.